# JSON object passed into Podio API Filter function doesn't seem to work

Tags: json, podio, klipfolio

I'm sending a POST request from klipfolio to https://api.podio.com/item/app/{app_id}/filter/ and specifying JSON object in body area provided. However, no matter what parameters I specify in the json object they do not seem to work. I used parameters as per Podio api documentation:

```
{
  "sort_by": The sort order to use,
  "sort_desc": True to sort descending, false otherwise,
  "filters": The filters to apply
  {
    "{key}": The value for the key filtering,
    ... (more filters)
  },
  "limit": The maximum number of items to return, defaults to 30,
  "offset": The offset into the returned items, defaults to 0,
  "remember": True if the view should be remembered, false otherwise
}
```

=> But this doesn't work

```
{ 
  "limit": 50 
}
```

=> Or this

```
{
    "sort_by": id,
    "sort_desc": true,
    "filters": {
        "id": {
            "from": 50,
            "to": 99
        }
    },
    "limit": 50,
    "offset": 0,
    "remember": false
}
```

I've tried a variety of parameters, nothing seems to effect results. Even something as simple as setting limit to 50 doesn't work - it still spits out 20 results. Any ideas?

After inspecting the post request, I can see that

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryjHNZ1IQyAQII1ZrI
```

Which leads me to believe klipfolio doesn't actually allow one to post json object as data. What.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a header in the Query Parameters section with a name of 'Content-Type' and a value of 'application/json'.